# Arithmetic or logical right shifts

Tags: c, bitwise

Is this code correct? Is there any major improvement I can ad in terms of number of operations?

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* function that yields 1 when run on a machine that uses
arithmetic right shifts for int's and 0 otherwise */

/* use only << >> ! & ~ ^ and constants between 0x0 and 0xff*/

int int_what_shifts();

int main(){
    int_what_shifts();
}

int int_what_shifts(){

    int mask = (0x80 << 24);

    printf("%d\n",!!(mask>>31));

    return !!(mask >> 31);
}
```

Comment: Does the code what you expect to do? The question of you "Is this correct" should be answered by you. If the answer is yes => change question to can you review mine code, if answer is no => off topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `24` with `(sizeof(int) - 1) * CHAR_BIT`. Otherwise the code would fail on a non-32-bit integer machines. Also, using `-1` as a probe makes you independent of the bitness of a system:

```
return ((-1) >> 1) == (-1);
```

PS: you don't want to print anything from such a specialized routine.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `((-1) >> 1) == (-1)` won't work if the system uses sign-magnitude signed type, although we can hardly seen it in modern systems anymore

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I know. It will also not work on 1-complement systems...

Comment: ah yes, don't know why I though that -1 in one's complement is also all 1 bits

Answer (score 2):

Your function *always* return 1 on machines with 32-bit int because `mask >> 31` will return 1 or ~0 depending on that compiler uses arithmetic or logical shift right, and apply `!!` to `mask >> 31` makes it return 1. Also, you should print the result of the function instead of printing in the function and discard the result.

Also note that people often use `1 << 31` rather than `0x80 << 24`. And you need `U` suffix to make sure that it doesn't invoke undefined behavior due to overflow. `(int)((signed char)0x80) << 24` will be OK in case `CHAR_BIT == 8` but `0x80 << 24` won't, because 0x80 is a positive number in the range of `int`, and shifting it 24 bits cause the number to overflow

```
#define NUM_BITS (sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT)

int mask = (int)(0x01U << (NUM_BITS - 1));    
return (mask >> (NUM_BITS - 1)) != 1;
```

But to be efficient, use

```
return ((~0) >> 1) == (~0);
```

instead. It'll work regardless of the signed type form because like I said in the other comment, vnp's solution won't work if the system uses sign-magnitude form.

Even better, define the function as macro or inline it.

Comment: `~0` may be a trap in one's complement (it is negative zero). Also, `(int)(1u << (NUM_BITS-1))` may raise a signal due to out-of-range conversion: the unsigned expression is out of range for signed int.   Same with `(signed char)0x80`.

Answer (score 1):

1. The premise is questionable.  `int mask = (0x80 << 24);`  Performing enough left shifts on an `int` on a positive number that exceeds `INT_MAX` is **undefined behavior**.  C11dr §6.5.7 4
2. In C, an `int` with a negative value right shifted is implementation-defined behavior.  That is what this function appears to address with `!!(mask >> 31);`.  Suggest not starting with the above UB.

   ```
   int int_what_shifts(void) {
     // Assume unsigned bit width completely covers int
     union {
       unsigned u;
       int i;
     } x;
     /* use only << >> ! & ~ ^ and constants between 0x0 and 0xff*/
     unsigned maxu = ~0u;  // all bits set
     x.u = maxu;
     x.i = x.i >> 1;
     // An arithmetic right shift on an all 1's pattern, results in all 1's
     return !(x.u ^ maxu);  // Test for equality
   }
   ```
3. `int_what_shifts()` should be `int_what_shifts(void)`.
4. 24 and 31 are magic numbers that useless in C for this purpose.  C does not define an `int` to be 32-bit 2's compliment.  In C, `int`s are *at least* 16-bits and 64-bit `int are not unheard of.

Comment: Why don't you just do `int i = ~0;` ?   If this is a trap then so is your access of `x.i`, and if it isn't then it's fine.

Comment: @Matt McNabb Agree that our 2 approaches would likely both set off a trap if the other did.  The code above has the slight advantage if `int i = ~0` was a trap and ` x.i = x.i >> 1;` did not cause a trap, things would work.  Of course your approach has the advantage in a reverse case.

Comment: I think reading `x.i` after doing `x.u = ~0u;` must get the same result as `x.i = ~0;`. All bits are set in both cases. So either approach traps if `~0` is a trap.  However the standard is slightly vague on the behaviour of `~` , in other places it specifically says if a result may be undefined or implementation-defined ; but it doesn't say anything for `~`.

Comment: @Matt McNabb Setting the trap issue aside, I heard tell of an unusual `unsigned` that had a range `0...INT_MAX`.  Thus your idea of `int i = ~0` may be good in that case.

Comment: I think that does not conform: `unsigned int` is specified as it must have a pure binary representation; and `int` must have a sign bit.

Comment: @Matt McNabb I think is was something like `unsigned` --> 0 to 2147483647 and `int` --> -2147483648 to 2147483647.  IAC, in 2014, just do not come across non 2's complement anymore.

Comment: those ranges are not permitted in Standard C

Answer (score 0):

According to the C standard, doing this test invokes implementation-defined behaviour, and it need not be either of a logical shift or arithmetic shift!

Also, C allows padding bits. (For example, unsigned int could be 32-bit, but signed int could be 30 value bits, 1 sign bit, and 1 padding bit; and the padding bit could be a parity check bit positioned in the MSB.

Allowing for this is pretty annoying so let's assume we are on a system that's not 40 years old, and thus it has no padding bits in `int`; and also assume that the shift is either arithmetic or it isn't.

Then we can just go:

```
return (-1 >> 1) >= 0;
```

`-1` has the sign bit set; on an arithmetic shift the sign bit will remain set afterwards; and on a logical shift the sign bit will become unset.